# My code is returning "Command '['python3']' timed out after 2 seconds"

Tags: python

Please help me with the following:

- given a list of sublists: [['a', 3], ['b', 5], ['c', 5], ['d', 4]]
- goal is to return the letter with the highest value attached
- if there is a tie, return the latter (in the above list, 'c' should be returned)

Currently I have:

```
nums = []
for i in list:
    nums.append(i[1])
while i in list:
    if max(nums) == i[1]:
        return i[0]
```

Can someone tell me why I'm seeing "Command '['python3']' timed out after 2 seconds"? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your second loop supposed to be a `for` rather than a `while`? This looks like a typo to me.

Comment: Yes it was. Thanks for catching it.

Answer (score 1):

Because at the end of the `for` loop `i` is equal to `['d', 4]`. Now you are doing `while i in list` which is `True`. And since `i[1] == 4 != 5 == max(nums)` you, my sir, have an infinite loop.

---

A different approach for this would be using the built-in [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) function with a costume `key` that will compare the second element. Then, to get the letter we will take the first element of the result. And since you want to return the last occurence, we will check the list [reversed](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) (`max` returns the first occurence):

```py
from operator import itemgetter

a = [['a', 3], ['b', 5], ['c', 5], ['d', 4]]

print(max(reversed(a), key=itemgetter(1))[0])
```

Gives: `c`

---

Going with your initial line of thought, first of all you might want to save that `max` value in a variable because each time you call `max` you loop the list again. Then, change the `while` to a `for` and loop the list from the end to return the last occurence. Oh, and don't name your lists `list`!

```py
def find_max_letter(a):
    nums = []
    for i in a:
        nums.append(i[1])
    # you can also create this with list-comprehension: nums = [i[1] for i in list]
    max_num = max(nums)
    for i in a[::-1]:
        if max_num == i[1]:
            return i[0]
```

Comment: Thank you so much Tomerikoo! Is it a style error if the first for statement doesn't return an expression but the second one does?

Comment: @txy00 it is not about style. It is about need. Please notice that `return` statements are only relevant **inside functions**. They return the value to the caller of the function. So it is not about style, it is about what is needed to be returned by the function

Comment: Ok I see. Thanks again!